# Open csv using Python using relative filepath

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Downloads")
```

I'm getting stuck with reading in files in Python.
Why does specifying the relative file path not work when reading the file?

```
files = os.listdir(r"csvfilestoimport")
```

```
files
['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
```

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File file.csv does not exist:'file1.csv'
```

Comment: Does the file exist? In the second case you write to another filename.

Comment: In the first case, you are reading an existing file. In the second case you are creating a file

Comment: Yes I want to read an existing file, do some analysis and export as xlsx. The file exists in the folder since the full filepath works when reading the csv.

Comment: is the change of the current directory successful? what does `os.getcwd()` say after you run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os` was my choice before I learned about `pathlib`.

---

```py
from pathlib import Path


path = Path("C:\Downloads")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in path.rglob("*.csv")])
```

---

With `pathlib` you don't have to join directory and file manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new file with a name you are sure that doesn't exist before (in your entire computer), and check that it is created in the folder you think. Then try to read it.

Ok, now with your example. Please, note that

```
files = os.listdir(r"csvfilestoimport")
['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
```

really means

```
['csvfilestoimport\file1.csv', 'csvfilestoimport\file2.csv']
```

So, you need to add this folder (**r"csvfilestoimport"**+f)

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(r"csvfilestoimport\"+f) for f in files])
```

Comment: I'm getting: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 1):

See this eg.

```
root_path = r"C:\Downloads"
filelist = glob.glob(f"{root_path}//*.csv")
df1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in filelist])
```

Answer (score 0):

In OS.chdir() try giving the full path of the downloads "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads" and try again

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads')
```

Comment: if your code is not in the same folder where your source file is, then while changing the directory you should mention that in full